# Spark - Datediff for months?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is there a good way to use `datediff` with months? To clarify: the `datediff` method takes two columns and returns the number of *days* that have passed between the two dates. I'd like to have that in *months*. I want to have a parameter in my function that can I tell to check data say from the last 20, 36, whatever months. If I just do datediff and divide the result with 30 (or 31), than the result is not quite accurate. I could use 30.4166667 (= 365 days/12 months), but that is not quite accurate either for shorter periods. So, any tips on how to use `datediff` to be able to get months out of it? SQL has it like `SELECT DATEDIFF(month, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');`, I'm looking for something like this in Spark.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try [`months_between`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#months_between(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column)):

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*
DataFrame newDF = df.withColumn("monthDiff", months_between(col("col1"), col("col2"))
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import months_between

data = sqlContext.sql('''
SELECT DISTINCT mystartdate,myenddate,
 CAST(months_between(mystartdate,myenddate) as int) as months_tenure
FROM mydatabase
''')
```